# Single Django model, multiple tables?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have several temporary tables in a MySQL database that share the same schema and have dynamic names. How would I use Django to interface with those tables? Can a single model draw data from multiple tables?

Comment: you can set it dynamically as updated below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could, I believe, make a factory function that would return your model with a dynamic [db_table](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table).

```
def getModel(db_table):
  class MyClass(models.Model):
     # define as usual ...
     class Meta:
       db_table = db_table

  return MyClass

newClass = getModel('29345794_table')
newClass.objects.filter( ...
```

EDIT: Django does not create a new instance of the class's `_meta` attribute each time this function is called. Creating a new instance for `_meta` it is dependent upon the name of the class (Django must cache it somewhere). A metaclass can be used to change the name of the class at runtime:

```
def getModel(db_table):
  class MyClassMetaclass(models.base.ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
      name += db_table
      return models.base.ModelBase.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

  class MyClass(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyClassMetaclass

    class Meta:
      db_table = db_table

  return MyClass
```

<strike>not sure if it can be set dynamically on an already-defined class.  I haven't done this myself but it might work.</strike>

You can set this whenever.

```
>>> MyModel._meta.db_table = '10293847_table'
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: I think your first solution is better in my situation, since I'll have any number of tables that have to be interfaced with and I'm not sure that setting it dynamically is a thread-safe solution. The problem I've discovered is that there are strange results when testing, namely that some wrangling has to be done to get fixtures loaded, and even then there is some strange behavior.

Comment: For your first solution, it looks like `db_table` is stuck at whatever is first assigned. It can be reassigned, but it is reassigned for every instance of the class (in other words, it seems that there is only one instance of `_meta`).

Comment: The second solution works for me. Saving record: myClass = get_model('tableName')
    t = myClass(description='nice' # set column value
    t.save()

Comment: when use `MyModel._meta.db_table` in multi-threads, is it dangerous?

Comment: for Python 3 code class MyClass(models.Model): __metaclass = MyClassMetaclass should be like this class MyClass(models.Model, metaclass = MyClassMetaclass):

Answer (score 9):

Create a model for your table dynamically.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

def create_model(db_table):

    class CustomMetaClass(ModelBase):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
            model = super(CustomMetaClass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
            model._meta.db_table = db_table
            return model

    class CustomModel(models.Model):

        __metaclass__ = CustomMetaClass

        # define your fileds here
        srno = models.IntegerField(db_column='SRNO', primary_key=True)

    return CustomModel
```

and you can start querying the database.

```
In [6]: t = create_model('trial1')

In [7]: t._meta.db_table
Out[7]: 'trial1'

In [8]: t.objects.all()  # default db
Out[8]: [<CustomModel: CustomModel object>, '(remaining elements truncated)...']

In [9]: t.objects.using('test').all()  # test db
Out[9]: [<CustomModel: CustomModel object>, '(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

Comment: It's the best answer. I've driven into Django source code and found that any model inherits from `models.Model` will be cached.  So `meta class` is needed to set different `model name` (cache key) and set different `model._meta.db_table`.

Comment: Amazing answer! But how such a solution will deal with DB migrations, tables creation and scheme updating? Is it possible to use a list of existing table names to support usual Django scheme upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

combined many stackflow answer to reach this

#connection should be passed from the django_project
#using django.db import connection

```
 class multiModel():

def __init__(self, model_name, table_name, prototype, app_name, connection) -> None:
    """
        @model_name: name of the new table object
        @table_name: name of the table with which it has to
                     be created in database
        @prototype: model which has to be used as prototype for
                    creating new table 

        @app_name: app for which table has to be created

        @connection: connection to be used


    """

    self.model_name = model_name
    self.table_name = table_name
    self.prototype = prototype
    self.app_name = app_name
    self.connection = connection
    self.name_table_db = f"{self.app_name}_{self.table_name}"


def get(self):

    if self.__exists__():

        Model = self.__create_model__(create=False)


    else:

        Model = self.__create_model__()

    return Model



def __exists__(self):

    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        
        cursor.execute("show tables;")
        tables = [each[0] for each in cursor.fetchall()]

    result = False

    if self.name_table_db.lower() in tables:
        
        result = True

    return result

    



def __create_model__(self, create = True):

    class Meta:
        pass

    setattr(Meta, "db_table", self.name_table_db)
    #self.db_table = f"{self.app_name}_{self.table_name}"

    fields = {}

    for field in self.prototype._meta.fields:

        fields[field.name] = field.clone()

    attrs = {'__module__':f"{self.app_name}.models", "Meta":Meta}
    self.attrs = attrs
    attrs.update(fields)


    model = type(self.model_name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    if create:
        
        with self.connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor: schema_editor.create_model(model)

    return model
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.