# Single Django model, multiple tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know this exact same question has been previously asked, but I was hoping for a 'better' answer (that does not involve modifying class attributes at runtime). This was the question:

[Single Django model, multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables)

I have the same problem - I am looking for a solution similar to the responder's first reply, but that actually works. If there is no better solution, can anyone comment on how reliable the responder's solution is? It seems to me that the delay between changing the database name and querying the database could end up returning results from the wrong table:

query 1: change the name

query 2: change the name again

query 1: get results (but using the incorrect name from query 2)

Edit: The model is intended for use on ~15 tables - so inheritance is impractical, since it would require a new model name every time.

Thanks

P.S. My apologies if this is not the correct way of asking for an elaboration on a question.

Comment: why do you prefer different tables over different models?

Comment: Because if I used models, I would need 15 of them. This is also intended to be a multi-db setup, so that would be 15 models each for four or 5 databases. It seems like a lot of code for something which (imo) only really needs 1 model. Creating 15 different models for tables with identical fields just doesn't seem right.

Comment: so you prefer handle 15 string combinations rather than 15 probably more explicits behaviour-like models? I'm writing you an answer

Comment: Yes, because the string combinations are explicitly referred to on the page. Having a generic model able to access every table is a good solution, and makes for readable, organized code. No sense in being very explicit if they end up referring to the same thing anyways.

Comment: In fact the table name and database seems to be stored at class level and not at instance level... So a bit like static attribute it seems dangerous to do what you want. You may want to make a class decorator. So with inheritance and a decorator you'll have only 3 lines by classes

Comment: Right - the table name is taken from the class name in django, unless the user defines a db_table name under a Meta subclass. Changing this will change the table the db accesses. This was the solution from the previous topic, however, changing this on the fly could lead to problems. But even with the meta class and the name, you still end up with 3 lines per table. This works out to 45 extra lines of code, which is itself not unreasonable. It just seems like there could be a better solution.

Comment: I think I've finished my answer after many edits, please feedback if it don't works or don't really suit your needs (I'm french)

Answer (score 2):

for a dynamic table and database interhangeable model with a more sexy behaviour than the one in your linked question you may use simple methods or properties:

```
import copy

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # anything
    @property
    def table_name(self):
        return self._meta.db_table

    @table_name.setter
    def table_name(self, value):
        new_meta = copy.copy(self._meta)
        new_meta.db_table = value
        self._meta = new_meta

    @classmethod
    def set_qs_for_table(cls, qs, table):
        my_class = copy.copy(cls)
        my_options = copy.copy(my_class._meta)
        my_class._meta = my_options
        qs.model = my_class
```

You may try something like this...

The copy part is to avoid danger of shared options between models. It took me time to find this part of the solution. but for the rest it looks sexy and straightforward.

Of course once in python code you may use

```
qs = MyClass.objects.all()
MyClass.set_qs_for_table(qs, "this_table")
my_instance = qs[0]
my_instance.table_name = "that_table"
my_instance.save(using="this_db")
```

Comment: The problem here is shared options - but the actual sharing is done behind the scenes in django, and is based on table name. Take this as an example:                                                     table = getModel(request.POST["table"])
table2 = getModel(request.POST["table"])

Comment: they are no more shared since I used copy and use a new options object insted of edit the shared one.

Comment: The problem here is shared options - but the actual sharing is done behind the scenes in django, and is based on table name. Take this as an example: table = getModel(request.POST["table"])
            table2 = getModel(request.POST["table"]) now we  do table._meta.db_table = 'test', but this gets changed for both. Changing the __name__ attribute does not work either, since both tables get updated. Also note that the only meta attribute needed is db_table. There are no other meta attributes.

Comment: Try my solution, I garantee you it's no more shared. My setter is that long to make instance level values and not class level shared values.

Comment: in fact it looks shared because _meta is an instance. if we modify this instance it will affect all users of that instances. Here I use a new memory address so it's not shared.

Comment: This solution doesn't work - the db_table attribute is not actually modified (which is weird, I did not expect this). As for the sharing - django handles this internally - a shallow copy will only overwrite the last class - try it.

Comment: Ok, sorry I belive you (I have no database to try).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A very useful snippet.

```
from django.db import models
shard_tables = {}
class ShardMixin():
    @classmethod
    def shard(cls, id=None):
        def get_ext(id):   # the multi tables rule
            return str(id % 100)  
        ext = get_ext(id)
        _db_table = "%s%s" % (cls._meta.db_table , ext)  # your table name
        if _db_table not in shard_tables:
            class Meta:
                db_table = _db_table
            attrs = {
                '__module__': cls.__module__,
                'Meta': Meta,
            }
            shard_tables[_db_table] = type("%s%s" % (cls.__name__, ext), (cls, ), attrs)
        return shard_tables[_db_table]

class User(models.Model, ShardMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=" username")
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        db_table = "user_"

users = User.shard(id=3).objects.values()
print(users)
```