# Create Multiple Tables From One Model In Django

Tags: django, django-models, limesurvey

I want to integrate [LimeSurvey](http://limesurvey.org) with my django application. LimeSurvey creates a survey with specific id and gives different tokens for survey users and save all tokens for specific survey in one table:

tables for a survey:

```
 survey_id
 token_id
```

and in tables:

```
 survey_898989
   id   submit_date  token .....

 tokens_898989
   tid  first_name  last_name  email  email_status  token
```

Edit: 898989 is survey id. I want to create tokens and insert in limesurvey token tables.

I want to create tokens with django. I need a model that creates multiple tables for each survey. Is there any way to create multiple tables from one model in django?

Thanks in advance

Comment: survey_898989 means that they are 898989 survey tables?

Comment: Why do you need a model here? Just use any python tool to work with your DB engine.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, Thanks for answer. I can use raw sql here but I want to know if is it possible with django.

Comment: No, Django ORM can't create new tables. And it has a philosophy of `model -> db table` (+ may be one more table for m2m relations). [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)'s the docs for raw SQL in Django.

Comment: @TheNone SQLAlchemy might be a better options here than Django. You could use "reflection" to load the limesurvey database and process it without having to reinvent models.

Comment: @DrTyrsa : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166269/single-django-model-multiple-tables/7166934#7166934