# Python Peewee: One Model Multiple Tables

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I'm currently implementing SQLite on Python using Peewee, and I couldn't figure out how to use a single model for multiple tables. The reason I need identical model for different tables is that each table will have a large number of rows. I need to perform `join()` operation between them, so changing only the `_meta.db_table` directly wouldn't help.

I have searched through SO for similar question (such as below), but they don't really address my question:

- [Single Django model, multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables)
- [Single Django model, multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166269/single-django-model-multiple-tables)

My simplified use case:

```
from peewee import *

database = SqliteDatabase('test.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class Student(BaseModel):
    name = TextField()
    date_of_birth = DateField()

class Course(BaseModel):
    student = ForeignKeyField(rel_model=Student, to_field='id', unique=True)
    score = IntegerField()
```

So let say I want to make multiple tables of the same model `Course()`, e.g. Bio101 and Bio201, and later I want to compare the `score` from those two courses for each overlapping student (student who registered on both courses).

How should I go about solving this, without actually changing the database schemas / structure (due to backward compatibility)?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem—i.e., I wanted to create multiple tables from the same model—and finally found a solution.

As an example, if you want to create multiple `Course` tables from a single model, you can use:

```
from peewee import *

database = SqliteDatabase('test.db')

class BaseModel(Model):
    student = ForeignKeyField(rel_model=Student, to_field='id', unique=True)
    score = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = database

# Create Course 1
class Course1(BaseModel):
    pass

# Create Course 2
class Course2(BaseModel):
    pass

database.create_tables([Course1, Course2])
```

The table `Course1` and `Course2` will have the same structure.