# django db_table not changing

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hi i have created a dynamic table model and it is not changing whenever i select another table from the list i ve created in the template...
if i select the first table to see the data of it and then go back to the list and select the second table i get this error

```
InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'table_name1.id' in 'field list'")
```

So, when I change from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tables/id=1` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tables/id=2` it gives me the error.

But if I restart the server and go straight to 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/tables/id=2` it works.

But now `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tables/id=1` it doesn't work.

this is the party of *views.py*

```
def addview(request, pk):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=pk)
    print table_name
    AllTables._meta.db_table = table_name.name
    print AllTables._meta.db_table
    tbl_detail = AllTables.objects.all()
    print tbl_detail

    return render(request, 'tables/table_list.html', {'details': tbl_detail})
```

The prints are just for testing and they work.
It prints out the correct table I select.
But the `tbl_detail` it doesn't print when i go to the 2nd table that i selected. only when I restart the server.

**CrawledTables holds all the table names inside that DB with the date of creation of each table. I get the table name of the CrawledTables and put it in the *AllTables._meta.db_table*.**

**AllTables access all the tables in the DB ( same structure, different table names with different data inside of each table)**

Do I need to clear the `db_table` everytime i go to the selected table?
I have done all the migrations correctly.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should do it like this : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables`

Comment: thank you..i will try that right now and let you know :)

Comment: thank you ...it worked ...thanks a lot

Comment: An upvote would give me 2 reps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single Django model, multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables)