# Django dynamic model for existing table "doesn't exist"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to take data from an existing MySQL table and place it into a model using the code from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables):

```
def getModel(table_name):
  class MyClassMetaclass(models.base.ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
      name += table_name
      return models.base.ModelBase.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

  class MyClass(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyClassMetaclass
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Time_stamp', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    price = models.DecimalField(db_column='Price', max_digits=8, decimal_places=3, blank=True,
                                null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
      db_table = table_name
      managed = False

  return MyClass
```

I then call the class as follows:

```
MyModel = getModel('test_table')
MyModel._meta.db_table = 'test_table'
```

and pass it into a DataPool (to create a chart using Django's Chartit):

```
pricedata = \
    DataPool(
       series=
        [{'options': {
           'source': MyModel.objects.all()},
          'terms': [
            'time_stamp',
            'price']}
         ])
```

At this point it throws an error **(1146, "Table 'meowdb.test_table' doesn't exist")**. Note that meowdb is the database name. Should it be prepending this?

I also don't actively pass the database into the model anywhere. According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/), it seems like once the model is created Django automatically links it based on the name?

Lastly, how do I get around this error? The table most certainly exists and is populated with many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out I was being a moron. I used Django to auto-generate the models and then picked one at random to try using the flexible model code with. I just so happened to pick one with a space in it's table name. The class model name showed up without spaces of course and I didn't realise it. So the table genuinely wasn't there!