# Django model - dynamically decide which table to user according to model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model, for the example, I will call it Book:

```
class Book(Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book'
```

i need dynamically to change 'db_table' according to book instance attribute

for example:
when id>100 choose 'book_new' table

so for query:

```
Book.objects.get(id=200)
```

'book_new' will be used.

also when creating a new Book (for 'new' attribute):

```
Book(name='ff', new=True).save()
```

a new record is added to 'book_new' (and not 'book')

- NOTE: i dont want to create new class, i need to use the same class, but to use a Manager(?) or Router(?) in order to choose the right db.

Update:

the reason to have it on one model is related to User object.
we have CustomUser that inherit Django AbstractUser.

I need to add another user to the system (lets call it User2), that has all User functionality + related tabled (like m2m table like auth_user_groups, etc..), so the only new table i need to add is 'auth_user2', and the m2m data will be kept at the same User tables 'auth_user'.

if we will add new class, we going to have many many changes that related to the m2m fields (naming tables, naming fields etc..)

also we dont want to change all the models that point to user class. (if we have Book class with foreign key to user, so book.user will return the requested user (user or user2 - according to user id)).
hope its clear.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    __metaclass__ = classmaker()

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user'

class Book(Model):
    name = CharField()
    user = ForeignKey(User)
```

so book.user will get user from auth_user tbl when id is less then 100, otherwise it will get user from 'auth_user2'

also all m2m fields for user and user2 are from the same tables. 
so user.groups and user2.groups will pull from the same table 'auth_user_groups'

Comment: Try this: [Single Django model, multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables)

Comment: its not based on object attribute values

Comment: This is very bad design, why would you need exactly this? For example, to implement what you want you would have to account for all possible manager and queryset methods, like `update`, `filter`, `get` etc.

Comment: lets say that this is the requirement.

Comment: I would say that the easiest way to maintain this is to have two Model instances that share the same queryset. This queryset would determine which model/table to query. It will take me a while to write it, so I'm going to ask before hand if you think you'd like it?

Comment: Could you tell us why you want to do that? That might help, really... Here is a random idea though: how about having 3 tables? One would only contain a generic foreign key: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations. An `AllBook` instance would refer to either an `OldBook` instance or a `NewBook` instance.

Comment: @Splatmistro  i updated my answer for the reason i want to do it in one model..

Comment: @FrançoisConstant  i updated my answer for the reason i want to do it in one model.

Comment: @Splatmistro i think it wont pass to have to model instances. i wanted to add custom manager, but without success

Comment: Do you have a (public) repo with this code in? Sound like a complex/bespoke case. Would help to see the codebase to really tailor the solution.

Comment: @Splatmistro updated. thanks.

Comment: I see no github link?

Comment: updated in my answer (a short code).

Comment: "I need to add another user to the system (lets call it User2)" I really don't understand why. If you're getting the same data and m2m relationships, why do you need a separate model?