# Django 1.11 - Use Model to query a clone table

Tags: django

I have a table `core_people` and a backup table `core_people_01`.

Is it possible to use `People` Django model to make a query on the "clone" table?

Something like this:

```
People.objects.get(pk = 123).table("people_01")
```

I've been searching online without success.

UPDATED AFTER COMMENT

Reading the other post on SO, I've tried that solution. In my models file I put this method:

```
def get_model(db_table):
  class MyClassMetaclass(People):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
      name += db_table
      return People.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

  class MyClass(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyClassMetaclass

    class Meta:
      db_table = db_table

  return MyClass
```

Using it with:

```
backup_people = get_model("core_people_01")
print (backup_people .objects.get(pk = 1234))
```

Pylint is telling me that MyClassMetaclass is invalid as MetaClass and trying to execute the above instruction, python tells me:

> RuntimeWarning: Model 'myclassmetaclass.core' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single Django model, multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

If you created the tables from the same model, then you can access the `_meta` attribute of the model to specify the table name you want to use like this.

> People._meta.db_table = 'core_people_01'
>
> People.objects.all()
>   ```

Comment: Its seems work. Unfortunally it seems that the table name override is "permanent" and not scoped in the method used so I need to restore the original table name after use.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a permanent requirement I would use model inheritance in the following way:

1) Transform your People model into an abstract model:

```
class AbstractPeople(models.Model):
    # Here your fields as in the original People model
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

2) Create two concrete models that extend from `AbstractPeople`

```
class People(AbstractPeople):
    pass

class BackupPeople(AbstractPeople):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'core_people_01'
        # You can include this if your table already exists 
        # and do not want Django to mess around with it
        managed = False
```

In this way both models have the same structure but they just get their data from different tables.

Comment: The Backup tables are related to months so there are lot of them. How can I istantiate BackupPeople changing table dynamically?

Comment: Are these tables too big? Can't you just simply craft a view that is the union of all your backup tables and relate the `BackupPeople` model to that view? Then, whenever you add a new backup table (i.e. every month) you just add a new `UNION` clause to your view definition.

Comment: That was an idea that implies to change the cron batch to drop and recreate the view with the new table. Its a possibility.

Comment: If a new table is generated once a month then you could also add a new `BackupPeople` once a month. Something in the line of `BackupPeople01`, `BackupPeople02`, etc. This of course is not very clean but depending on your use case it may be ok. If you want something more dynamic you should dig into how to dynamically add models to an already running django instance, but it may become obscure for someone that needs to take care of your app in the future.