# Acces data from other table - Foreign Key in Django Rest Api - Unknown column

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I created Django Rest Models from existing MySQL database with inspectdb. I have two models, and I want to access some data from other model.

My models:

```
class Impreza(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    tytul = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '2006_impreza'

class Description(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    year_id = models.IntegerField()
    id_imprezy = models.IntegerField(blank=True, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = '2006_description'
```

My serializer:

```
class ImprezaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    desc = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Impreza
        fields = ('year', 'tytul', 'desc')
```

My problem is that Django is searching for id named 'impreza_id', but it exists with other name - 'id_imprezy'. As you can see, I tried to give 'id_imprezy' a 'primary_key=True' to tell Django that this is the right name but it doesn't work. It still gives me error: ***(1054, "Unknown column '2006_description.impreza_id' in 'field list'")***.

In my database both tables have id, but it doesn't show up in the model. I read that Django isn't showing id columns in models.

How can I do it right? How to add foreign key?
Sorry, but I'm realy new to Django ;-)

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036357/single-django-model-multiple-tables

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer, you're referencing `model = Impreza`:

```
...
class Meta:
    model = Impreza
    fields = ('year', 'tytul', 'desc')
```

You're referencing the `Impreza` class, which actually has the fields `'year'` and `'tytul'`.  The `Impreza` class also contains a variable called `impreza_id`.  Because your serializer is looking for items in the `Impreza`, and not `Description`, Django gets ticked and tells you that it can't find `impreza_id`.

Changing which class you reference will not solve your problem, though.  If you would like to have a one-to-many relationship, you'll use a `ForeignKey`.

```
class Description(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    impreza = models.ForeignKey(Impreza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**All of these things said,** I would consider a different architecture altogether.  You're building a very specific class which could very well be modularized and reusable.  Consider just doing this:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    make = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

A solid use case for one-to-many relationships:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    make = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
```

In this case you can have one owner own many vehicles.

Cheers!